# Can loadImage() be used with a JavaScript Promise?

Tags: promise, p5.js

I'm writing an application draws particles on screen in a chemical reaction.

I have written a `Particle` class and **want to handle the async nature of loading images in P5.js in this class**.

My thinking was that if I wrap the `loadImage()` function in a Promise, I should be able to load all of my particle sprites async and then have the draw code execute as soon as the P5 Image object resolves.

I had this code working fine using just callback functionality of `loadImage()`, but I ultimately have to **hand off the image object to a physics library to model particle motion** as well as other constructors, so a Promise pattern seemed to be the right solution.

```
class Particle {

    constructor(name) {
        // Set properties on the Particle
        this.imageUrl = "THE_URL";
        this.imageObject = null;
    }

    loadParticleImage() {

        console.log("attempting to load image: " + this.imageUrl)

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            loadImage(this.imageUrl, (result) => {

                // Sets the image object property to the result for other methods to access
                this.imageObject = result;

                // Resolves the Promise with the result
                resolve(result);

            }, reject(Error("Image not found")));
        })
    }

    drawParticle() {

        console.log("attempting to draw particle");

        this.loadParticleImage().then(function (imageObject) {

            // code to draw image and handoff to physics library

        }, function (error) {
            console.log("imageObject not defined", error);
        });

    }

}
```

And in the `setup()` function of the main sketch file, I would initialize a particle and draw it using something like:

```
theParticle = new Particle("Water");
theParticle.drawParticle();
```

I get a stack error saying that the image could not be loaded and I can't quite figure out why.

```
attempting to draw particle
particle.js: attempting to load image: img/svg/Water.svg
particle.js: imageObject not defined Error: Image not found
at particle.js
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Particle.loadParticleImage (particle.js)
at Particle.drawParticle (particle.js)
at <anonymous>:1:18
```

Comment: `drawParticle` should only draw the loaded particle, not load it. Otherwise rename the method to `loadAndDrawParticle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can spot two mistakes in your code:

- you are always immediately calling `reject()`. You probably wanted to pass a callback to `loadImage` that will reject the promise:

  ```
  loadImage(this.imageUrl, (result) => {
      …
  }, () => {
  // ^^^^^^^
     reject(new Error("Image not found"));
  });
  ```
- [the `this` keyword in your callback is not the one you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572). Use an arrow function for the promise executor callback as well to have `this` refer to your `Particle` instance that `loadParticleImage` was called on:

  ```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  //                                   ^^
      loadImage(this.imageUrl, result => {
          this.imageObject = result;
          …
  ```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for pointing out these syntax problems. I just started to read about Promises the same day I was adapting this code, so definitely still learning. Much appreciate the insight!